# Acer Aspire V3-572G laptop freezes in the first screen after routine Ubuntu update

Tags: acer, bios

I have an Acer Aspire V3-572G. I run Ubuntu 15.10. Yesterday I installed some updates. As requested, I rebooted the computer and it froze at the very first screen with the Acer logo. I switched it off and on again and everything went fine. I got home later and i switched it again and the same story, computer freezes on the Acer splash screen. I found out that if I tried several times switching off and on more or less 1 out of 20 times it worked fine and the OS booted properly.

What is happening? It is very strange to me that an OS update could be responsible for a problem like this, pretty much because the OS is not even booted when the computer freezes, but on the other hand the problems did start right after that update so I cannot help but wonder if they are related.

So, what could it be and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a parameter in the BIOS so that now it does not by default show the ACER page splash screen, where the computer froze, but rather a screen with computer info. This did the trick.